# Save an .xls file in a specific folder

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, directory, xls

> I have a web_scraping script, which generates a download, resulting in
> a .xls file
>
> I can't save this .xls file in the folder I want.
>
> I would like to save it to a local folder
>
> I tried like this:

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

options = Options()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
  'download.default_directory': r'C:\Users\prmatteo\OneDrive - xxxS.A\Área de Trabalho\arquivos python'
})

driver.get('http://estatisticas.cetip.com.br/astec/series_v05/paginas/lum_web_v05_series_introducao.asp?str_Modulo=Ativo&int_Idioma=1&int_Titulo=6&int_NivelBD=2/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divContainerIframeBmf"]/div/dl/dd[2]/a').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[@name="dados_corpo"]'))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//frame[@name="ativo"]'))
find_dp1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//select[@name="ativo"]')
select_find_dp1 = Select(find_dp1)
select_find_dp1.select_by_visible_text("CBIO - Crédito de descarbonização")
time.sleep(3)

driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dados_corpo'))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'frameset').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'frame')[1])

time.sleep(1)
informacoes = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'selectopcoes'))
informacoes.select_by_visible_text('Estoque')

driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dados_corpo'))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'frameset').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'frame')[2])

time.sleep(1)
# Data Inicial 
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'DT_DIA_DE').send_keys('10')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'DT_MES_DE').send_keys('10')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'DT_ANO_DE').send_keys('2021')

# Data Final
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'DT_DIA_ATE').send_keys('30')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'DT_MES_ATE').send_keys('12')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'DT_ANO_ATE').send_keys('2022')

driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'button')[1].click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe'))
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'primary-text').find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'a').click()
```

> Utilizei este código para tentar direcioná-lo para uma pasta:

```
  options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
      'download.default_directory': r'C:\Users\prmatteo\OneDrive - xxxS.A\Área de Trabalho\arquivos python'
    })
```

> Porém, não funcionou.

Comment: Please take a look at: - 'shutil' package
specifically:- 'shutil.move'

Answer (score 1):

Copy or move a file from one directory to another:

```
import shutil
 
# source path
source = "/old_docs/file.xls"
 
# destination path
destination = "/new_docs/file.xls"
```

```
# copy file 
shutil.copy(source, destination)
```

```
# move file
shutil.move(source, destination)
```

Move or copy file with filename as variable:

```
filename = "file.xls"

# source path
source = "/old_docs/"
 
# destination path
destination = "/new_docs/"

# copy file
shutil.copy(source + filename, destination + filename)

# move file
shutil.move(source + filename, destination + filename)
```

Comment: and how do I transfer the downloaded .xls file, without having to specify its name?

Comment: You can use a variable and concatenate the variable name to the path: destination + my_file or source + my_file. I updated the answer with an example.